# Get product of the list items by using recursion in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

How do you get a product of the list items by using recursion?

If I ask:

```
product([s(0), s(s(0)), s(s(0))], S).
```

The result should be:

```
S = s(s(s(s(0)))).
```

But I geep geting wrong results. Or no results.

I tried:

```
product([], 0).
product([], Res).
product([H1, H2|T], Res) :- T\=[], mul(H1, H2, Res), product(T, Res).
product([H|T], Res) :- mul(H, Res, X), product(T, X).
```

mul is multiplication and it works fine.

If I use trace i can see that it finds th result but than it failes for some reason.

```
Call: (10) product([], s(s(s(s(0))))) ? creep
Fail: (10) product([], s(s(s(s(0))))) ? creep
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: `product([], Res).` says that the multiplication of no elements is anything you want. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `mul(H, Res, X)`?

Comment: "mul is multiplication and it works fine" - it doesn't work fine for us unless you post the code. You should always provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is a problem: `mul(H1, H2, Res), product(T, Res).`. This is likely to fail unless the `Res` in the first expression is unifiable the `Res` in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that this does the trick:

```
product([], 0).
product([H], H).
product([H1, H2|T], Res) :-
    mul(H1, H2, H),
    product([H|T], Res).
```

The first predicate is a trivial base case.

The second is where the list only contains a single element - so that's the answer.

The third is where you have a list of two or more elements - simply perform the `mul/3` on the first two and then recursively call `product/2`. This will eventually match predicate 2 and complete.

Your sample input does yield `s(s(s(s(0))))`.

Please in the future include the definition for `mul/3`. I had to search the internet to find one.

```
%Addition
sum(0,M,M). %the sum of an integer M and 0 is M.
sum(s(N),M,s(K)) :- sum(N,M,K). %The sum of the successor of N and M is the successor of the sum of N and M.

%Multiplication
%Will work for mul(s(s(0)),s(s(0)),X) but not terminate for mul(X,Y,s(s(0)))
mul(0,M,0). %The product of 0 with any integer is 0
mul(s(N),M,P) :- 
    mul(N,M,K), 
    sum(K,M,P). %The product of the successor of N and M is the sum of M with the product of M and N. --> (N+1)*M = N*M + M
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I forgot to add mul and sum.

Comment: @IshmaelBlack - No worries.